# How can I only calculate and store what is visible in a JTable?

Tags: java, swing, jtable

EDIT: Per camickr's advice, I made a couple of simple edits to this demo code:

```java
/*
 * TableDemo.java requires no other files.
 */

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.ZoneOffset;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Locale;

/** 
 * TableDemo is just like SimpleTableDemo, except that it
 * uses a custom TableModel.
 */
public class TableDemo extends JPanel {
    private boolean DEBUG = false;

    public TableDemo() {
        super(new GridLayout(1,0));

        JTable table = new JTable(new MyTableModel());
        table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(500, 70));
        table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);

        //Create the scroll pane and add the table to it.
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
        scrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);

        //Add the scroll pane to this panel.
        add(scrollPane);
    }

    class MyTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {
        private String[] columnNames = {"Seconds Since Epoch",
                                        "Formatted Timestamp"};

        public int getColumnCount() {
            return columnNames.length;
        }

        public int getRowCount() {
            return Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        }

        public String getColumnName(int col) {
            return columnNames[col];
        }

        public Object getValueAt(int row, int col) {
            if (col == 0) {
                return row;
            }

            return getPrettyStringFromEpochSeconds((long) row);
        }

        private String getPrettyStringFromEpochSeconds(long seconds) {
            LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.ofEpochSecond(seconds, 0, ZoneOffset.UTC);
            DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("h:mm:ss a EEEE, MMMM d, yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
            String formattedDate = dateTime.format(formatter);
            return formattedDate;
        }

        /*
         * JTable uses this method to determine the default renderer/
         * editor for each cell.  If we didn't implement this method,
         * then the last column would contain text ("true"/"false"),
         * rather than a check box.
         */
        public Class getColumnClass(int c) {
            return c == 0 ? Integer.class : String.class;
        }

    }

    /**
     * Create the GUI and show it.  For thread safety,
     * this method should be invoked from the
     * event-dispatching thread.
     */
    private static void createAndShowGUI() {
        //Create and set up the window.
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("TableDemo");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        //Create and set up the content pane.
        TableDemo newContentPane = new TableDemo();
        newContentPane.setOpaque(true); //content panes must be opaque
        frame.setContentPane(newContentPane);

        //Display the window.
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Schedule a job for the event-dispatching thread:
        //creating and showing this application's GUI.
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I *think* this is working, but I can't actually scroll down and find out. Any ideas why the scrollbar I added is not actually doing anything?

|----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|

So I want to create a JTable with 2 columns: one containing ascending numbers from 0 (with no upper bound!) and the other column containing a string that I derive from the number in the same row. Since this table is technically infinite in size, I would like to only compute and display as many rows that fit on the screen, and change the values of the table based on a vertical scrollbar. For example, if the window is currently sized so that only 3 rows fit on the screen, I want the table to look like this:

```
|---------------------|------------------|
|      Heading 1      |     Heading 2    |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          0          |       Str0       |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          1          |       Str1       |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          2          |       Str2       |
|---------------------|------------------|
```

But after scrolling down one row I want it to look like this:

```
|---------------------|------------------|
|      Heading 1      |     Heading 2    |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          1          |       Str1       |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          2          |       Str2       |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          3          |       Str3       |
|---------------------|------------------|
```

Is there a relatively simple way of dynamically computing and rendering these values so that my memory footprint scales with my screen size as opposed to the size of my dataset?

Comment: A JTable can only display data from the TableModel. If the second column is derived, then override the `getValuaAt(...)1 method of a custom TableMode. If the columns is 0, then you would just return the row number. If the column is 1, then you derive the String value. You would also need to override the `getRowCount(...)` method to return some value.  See [Creating a TableModel](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#data) for more information and examples.

Comment: @camickr thanks for the response! I looked through the link you commented and am not seeing anything regarding `getValueAt(...)` when the dataset is infinite. I want a user to be able to scroll down forever and keep seeing new values (or at least until they hit `Long.MAX_VALUE` or something)

Comment: *not seeing anything regarding getValueAt(...)* - what do you mean? The example implements 6 methods, including `getValueAt(...)`. You obviously can't use the implementation in the example because it is based on data being stored in a fixed size Array. I suggested how you could implement that method without any storage. It is up to you to customize the method for your requirements. We don't know how you will "derive" the value. And yes, you would need to use Integer.MAX_VALUE as the arbitrary limit since all other methods accept "int" parameters.

Comment: So I suggest you download the `TableDemo` code and modify the model for your requirement. Customizing `getRowCount()` will be easy, you just return Integer.MAX_VALUE. If you have problems. then post what you have tried.

Comment: @camickr I edited my post with my code, now the table is fine but I can't scroll for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

You can't set the row count to `Integer.MAX_VALUE`.  The largest number that worked was `65536 * 2048 - 1`.

Here's the code I ran.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.ZoneOffset;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Locale;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;

/**
 * TableDemo is just like SimpleTableDemo, except that it uses
 * a custom TableModel.
 */
public class TableDemo extends JPanel {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

//  private boolean DEBUG = false;

    public TableDemo() {
        super(new BorderLayout());

        JTable table = new JTable(new MyTableModel());
        table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(
                new Dimension(500, 16 * 10));
        table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);

        // Create the scroll pane and add the table to it.
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
        scrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(
                JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);

        // Add the scroll pane to this panel.
        add(scrollPane);
    }

    class MyTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        private String[] columnNames = { "Seconds Since Epoch",
                "Formatted Timestamp" };

        @Override
        public int getColumnCount() {
            return columnNames.length;
        }

        @Override
        public int getRowCount() {
            return 65536 * 2048 - 1;
        }

        @Override
        public String getColumnName(int col) {
            return columnNames[col];
        }

        @Override
        public Object getValueAt(int row, int col) {
            if (col == 0) {
                return row;
            }

            return getPrettyStringFromEpochSeconds(row);
        }

        private String getPrettyStringFromEpochSeconds(long seconds) {
            LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.ofEpochSecond(
                    seconds, 0, ZoneOffset.UTC);
            DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(
                    "h:mm:ss a EEEE, MMMM d, yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
            String formattedDate = dateTime.format(formatter);
            return formattedDate;
        }

        /*
         * JTable uses this method to determine the default
         * renderer/ editor for each
         * cell. If we didn't implement this method, then
         * the last column would contain
         * text ("true"/"false"), rather than a check box.
         */
        @Override
        public Class<?> getColumnClass(int c) {
            return c == 0 ? Integer.class : String.class;
        }

    }

    /**
     * Create the GUI and show it. For thread safety, this method
     * should be invoked from the event-dispatching thread.
     */
    private static void createAndShowGUI() {
        // Create and set up the window.
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("TableDemo");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        // Create and set up the content pane.
        TableDemo newContentPane = new TableDemo();
        // content panes must be opaque
        newContentPane.setOpaque(true);
        frame.setContentPane(newContentPane);

        // Display the window.
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Schedule a job for the event-dispatching thread:
        // creating and showing this application's GUI.
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```